# Метка местоположения пользователя mapKit ios

Tags: ios, map

Делал проект с картами, там отметка местоположения пользователя была в виде синей точки, сейчас делаю проект - отметка в виде черной точки. Подскажите, из-за чего это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с этим вопросом. Решение: self.mapview.tintColor = UIColor.youColor()
Либо можно в настройках изменить Tint.